# Checking if datatable is empty

Tags: jquery, datatable

I try to build a table which is both a JQuery treeTable and a JQuery datatable at the same time.
Attention please, my problem is not about how to use it both, i can view without problem if i fill the "table".

But when i send an empty array to my treetable building code, i am getting error.

Here are problem lines:

```
$('#table tbody tr').each(function(){
                        console.log(this);
                        if(mytable.fnGetData(mytable.fnGetPosition(this))[4]){
                            console.log('in set child before');
                            $(this).addClass('child-of-'+mytable.fnGetData(mytable.fnGetPosition(this))[4]);
                            console.log('in set child after');
                        }
                        $(this).attr('id', mytable.fnGetData(mytable.fnGetPosition(this))[0]);
                    });
```

When i do not populate the table, despite my wish, the process goes through to the above loop, and

`console.log(this)` prints out:

```
<tr class="odd"><td valign="top" colspan="4" class="dataTables_empty">No data available in table</td></tr>
```

So it generates error, because the row data is not an expected one.

I want to ask, what is the most elegant way to control if it is a populated "data", or an empty warning row? Is checking the "class" for "dataTables_empty" an appropriate method?

Or is there any other way to not to go through above loop if table is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583807/jquery-datatables-ajax-reloading-how-to-catch-when-nothing-is-returned

Comment: exact duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193051/how-can-i-prevent-the-jquery-datatable-plugin-from-adding-row-and-message-when-t

Comment: i want an empty message to appear when table is empty, but also want to check if it is empty or not. anyway i am using `$(this).find(td:first).hasClass('dataTables_empty')` thanks anyway

Answer (score 12):

How know if Datatable is empty

```
var table = $('#idTable').DataTable();

if ( ! table.data().any() ) {
    alert( 'Empty table' );
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also check if dataTable is empty using page.info() as described in this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163428/how-to-get-filtered-row-count). 
eg.

```
    //gives the total number of filtered records
    var totalDisplayRecord = $(".dTable").DataTable().page.info().recordsDisplay
(totalDisplayRecord === 0)? alert("table is empty") : alert("table is not empty");
```

or

```
//gives the total number of records in table
var totalRecords =$(".dTable").DataTable().page.info().recordsTotal;
//test if dataTable is empty
(totalRecords === 0)? alert("table is empty") : alert("table is not empty");
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way

```js
var count = $("table.dTable").dataTable().fnSettings().aoData.length;
if (count == 0)
{
   alert("Please enter the Data");
}else{
   alert("Table contains " + count + ' rows');
}
```

```html
<table class="dTable"></table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you could have just edited @elad silver answer instead of posting a new one that is the same but with an editor, thoughts for next time ;)

Answer (score 1):

from the [forum](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/15474/how-to-check-data-table-is-empty-or-not) this might be what you're looking for:

```
table.fnSettings().aoData.length
```

gives You the length of data in table. So if it will be equal to 0 then there is no data.

```
    if(table.fnSettings().aoData.length===0) {
        alert('no data');
    } else {
        alert('data exists!');
    }
```

Comment: pretty old answer so please comment if it doesn't work