# How to count the number of combination of rows with a drop down list selection in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I would like to count the number of rows in a table after making a selection in a drop down list (Name). but the only problem here is i would like to count number of rows basing on an other attribute in my table (position). 
for example:
if i make a selection in the   **Name: Tiger Nixon**
i would like to get 
**total rows: 3**
**Position 1  : 1  rows**   **Position 2  : 1 rows**  **Position 3  : 1 rows**

Here the code I use to make a drop down list selection with attribute (Name) and it worked perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            initComplete: function () {
                this.api().columns(0).every(function () {
                    var column = this;
                    var select = $('<select class="Search"><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo($(column.header()))
                        .on('change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each(function (d, j) {
                        select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>')
                    });
                });
            }
        });

        $('.Search').change(function () {               
            if ($("#example > tbody > tr > td").length == 1) {
                $('#Count').empty();

                $('#Count').append('Count: 0' );;
            } else {
                $('#Count').empty();
                $('#Count').append('Count: ' + $("#example > tbody > tr").length);
            }
        });
    });
```

[this pict for counting number of rows using just selection on Name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeBFi.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get filtered row count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163428/how-to-get-filtered-row-count)

Comment: Yep, it's a duplicate of that thread @PeterB mentioned above - just use `$('#table_id').DataTable().page.info().recordsDisplay`

Comment: thanks for ur ansers guys. i found a half solution. could you please see how can solve this. i edited the question a litte bit thanks.

Comment: @colin0117 is it possible to    $('#table_id').DataTable().page.info().recordsDisplay        to count number of rows with a specific value? thanks

Comment: No, page.info() returns information about the current dataset. You could use filter() to determine that - see https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()

Comment: @ colin0117 exactly i used this one and it returns what i want but for the whole dataset. if i could find a way to return just count of nb rows but after selection on a drop down list that will be awesome.filter() works for the whole dataset. but i want just a specific dataset to count on. (i get it with a drop down selection)